# moving files with different file name

Tags: shell, cp, mv

I have identical looking but totally different 4 files.

```
> _palus_SLA_response_pages_main_2c3cd_2_18.tokudb
> _palus_SLA_response_pages_status_2c3cd_1_18.tokudb
> _palus_SLA_response_pages_main_51fdda_2_18.tokudb
> _palus_SLA_response_pages_status_51fdda_1_18.tokudb
```

I need to replace all the files having a code "**51fdda**" with the other one "**2c3cd**".
So the new code will overwrite the files with old code and there will be only 2 files left:

```
_palus_SLA_response_pages_main_2c3cd_2_18.tokudb
_palus_SLA_response_pages_status_2c3cd_1_18.tokudb
```

I can move each file one at a time, something like this...

```
mv "_palus_SLA_response_pages_main_51fdda_2_18.tokudb" "_palus_SLA_response_pages_main_2c3cd_2_18.tokudb" 
mv "_palus_SLA_response_pages_status_51fdda_1_18.tokudb" "_palus_SLA_response_pages_status_2c3cd_1_18.tokudb"
```

But there are too many files to be moved at a time manually. I need a script that will do this for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the `rename` command available, you can use that:

```
rename 51fdda 2c3cd *tokudb
```

If you do not have the rename command available, you can do this with a simple loop:

```
for file in *51fdda*.tokudb; do
    mv ${file} ${file/51fdda/2c3cd}
done
```

For more information about this second solution, see the "Brace Expansion" section of the `bash(1)` man page.